# Average values in an array of hashes with duplicate keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, average

I have an array of hashes set up as below:

```
array = [
  {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3},
  {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}, 
  {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}
]
```

I'm trying to find a way to average the values of all the hashes with key `"1"`, for example.

Can someone help?

Comment: In future, consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. A quick selection may discourage other answers and some consider it disrespectful to those still working on their answers. Also, you might find that by waiting awhile (>= 2 hours perhaps) a better answer will appear.  The point is there's no rush. I know you're new to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'll take that on board. Yes new to stack overflow also so I'll make sure to keep this in mind when asking any other questions. Thanks again. Everyone have been very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the Ruby version, yield_self (alias then) might work:

```
[{ "1" => 10, "2" => 2, "3" =>3 },
 { "1" => 43, "2" => 2, "3" =>3 },
 { "1" => 4, "2" => 2, "3" =>3 }].map { |hash| hash.fetch('1', 0) }.then { |arr| arr.sum.fdiv(arr.size) }
# 19.0
```

Where `(10 + 43 + 4) / 3 = 19.0`, not your example, but not just 1 + 1 + 1.

Comment: fantastic thank you, worked like a treat!. On reflection my array was a little different, each key & value was in a different hash as they were added individually by a .push in a loop which meant your solution was mapping 'nil' (my fault). Tho i got past this by adding .compact before your .then to remove the nils.   Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Array has a `sum` method nowadays, which takes a block. It basically sums whatever the block returns:

```
array = [{"1" => 0, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}, {"1" => 1, "2" => 4, "3" =>6}, {"1" => 2, "2" => 6, "3" =>9}]
array.sum{|h| h['1']}.fdiv(array.size)
```

Comment: Best answer, imo. Note this assumes the array is not empty.

Comment: Nice use of sum, consider there will be a TypeError if there's a hash within the array without the '1' key (I fell for the same case).

Comment: @SebastianPalma you could do `{|h| h['1'].to_i }` to guard against nils.

Comment: That's pretty nice @steenslag

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
array = [{"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3},{"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3},{"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}]
array.map { |hash| hash['1'] }.inject { |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / array.size
#=> 1.0
```

`array.map { |hash| hash['1'] }` extracts the values for all elements with the key `'1'` (`[1,1,1]`) in this example. And `.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / array.size` calculates the average.

Answer (score 0):

Given the array (I changed the values for easy of debug):

```
array = [{"1" => 0, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}, {"1" => 1, "2" => 4, "3" =>6}, {"1" => 2, "2" => 6, "3" =>9}]
```

This code map each key to the average of values:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |k,v| k[v] = [ ]}) { |h, hh| h.each { |k,v| hh[k] << v } }.transform_values { |k| k.sum.to_f/k.size }

#=>  {"1"=>1.0, "2"=>4.0, "3"=>6.0}
```

---

Methods used:

- [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)
- [Hash#default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-default)
- [Enumerator#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-each)
- [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)
- [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-sum)
- [Array#size](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-size)

Answer (score 0):

```rb
array_data = [
  {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}, 
  {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}, 
  {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" =>3}
]

class Hash
  def get_first
    self['1']
  end
end

class Array
  def avg
    sum / size
  end
end

avg = array_data.map(&:get_first).avg
```